# Do dragons have gender?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Dragons are the most powerful creatures made by Morgoth. I'm just curious about whether or not dragons have gender.

Even Ainurs have gender and their own pair of another gender, right? But how about dragons? Do they have gender? I know Glaurung is referred to as 'he,' and 'the father of dragons', but is it a real male?

Comment: Yes, this question is directly answered in the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know that there was a similar one with my searching skill....

Comment: They're easily missed, hence why you have to mark what the duplicate is before you can flag it.